# Tensorflow shape error: Asking for input and output shape to match?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, reshape

I am new to Tensorflow, and I realize there are lots of posts out there about shape issues, but I haven't been able to quite apply their solutions to my problem. So please excuse me if this is a common/redundant issue.

Context: I am using image data to predict the genre of an image. More specifically, I have the pixel data (50x50x3) of many images that go into 1 of 4 categories [lanscape, portrait, abstract, other].

Code Specifics:
I'll try to display the code that might have the problem. There's of course other code in this project, but for simplicity I will omit it (or else it would be a hard post to read); however in a follow up I will go into more detail if a solution isn't found.

I one-hot encoded the labels using the following

`train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, dtype='float32')`

Then I loaded in the pixel data by supplying a tensor object with a list of image paths, and running the `load_image` function on all the paths (not shown).

```
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_files, train_labels)) 
train_data = train_data.map(load_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE) 
train_data = train_data.map(normalize, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE) 
train_data = train_data.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size) 
train_data = train_data.batch(batch_size)`
```

the `train_data` object appears as such:

`<_BatchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 50, 50, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>`

Which I believe makes sense because the input data is 50x50x3 (with a batch dimension) and the output dimension is 4 because of the one-hot encoding of 4 classes (with a batch dimension). The whole process and result is the same with my validation data.

However when I try to train my model there is a shape error:

```
def simple_FFNN(image_height, image_width, num_channels, num_classes):
    input_shape = \[image_height, image_width, num_channels\] # height, width, channels
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Input(shape=input_shape))
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(units=num_classes, activation='softmax'))

    return model

learning_rate = 0.01
epochs = 3
model = simple_FFNN(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, NUM_CHANNELS, NUM_CLASSES)
optimizer = optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate)
loss = losses.categorical_crossentropy
model.compile(loss=loss,
optimizer=optimizer,
metrics='accuracy')

training_results = model.fit(
    train_data,
    validation_data=validation_data,
    epochs=epochs,
    verbose=1)`
```

The error is:

`ValueError: Shapes (None, 4) and (None, 50, 50, 4) are incompatible`

The first shape is my output shape, and the 2nd shape is ALMOST my input shape but with the number of channels slightly off... Almost like the number of classes got subbed in.

Anyway, I can't figure out why the output shape and input shape would have to match in the first place. I must be misunderstanding the problem. Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

I tried removing the batching in `train_data.batch()` but then I got an error saying (None, 50, 50, 3) and (50, 50, 3) don't match (which made sense to me). Interestingly it showed (50, 50, 3) and not (50, 50, 4), so I can't figure out why the last dimension is getting swapped with a 4.

Answer (score 1):

A potential issue may arise due to a disparity between the initial input hidden layer architecture in the TensorFlow neural network model. Specifically, this layer consists of a fully connected component designed to accept input data with dimensions of (batch, num_features), whereas your input data possesses dimensions of (batch, height, width, channels). If you are not employing a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) structure, it is advisable to consider a preprocessing step in which the input features are reshaped, effectively flattening them into the format (batch, height*width*channels).

Answer (score 0):

The shape of your input images is (50, 50, 3) which indicates three color channels. However, your model's output layer is defined to have four units which shows that it expects a four-channel input.
Make sure the input shape of your model matches the shape of your input data to address this problem. Set the num_channels parameter in your model function to 3 because your images have three color channels.